# function definition in C

Tags: c, function

I can't get that why are we using a * in a function declaration like:

```
struct node *create_ll(struct node *)
{
    body here
}
```

Why do we use that * before create_ll which is the function name?
And it is called using the statement:

```
start = create_ll(start);
```

If this could help.
Please explain this.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 3):

`struct node *create_ll(struct node *)`

means the return type of this function will be a *pointer* of type `struct node`. read it like

`struct node *` ,

not like

`*create_ll`.

This has nothing to do with the **NAME** of the function.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Sourav (thought I'd elaborate further, and I can't comment due to low rep), using the * operator returns a **pointer** to the given type, this pointer is actually just a number that stores the starting memory address of the given object (the actual type of number depends on OS and processor... 32bit numbers on a 32bit OS/processor, 64bit numbers on a 64bit OS/processor) and not the actual object itself.

For instance: even if you have a 64bit processor, if you're running Windows XP (32bit) then the resulting number will be a 32bit number (4 bytes of memory to store), if you switched over to a 64bit OS then the resulting number would be a 64bit number (8 bytes of memory to store).

In order to get a pointer in the first place, the & operator is needed... unless dynamically allocated using malloc() or something similar.

When actually using the pointer, then the -> operator is used (instead of using the . operator).

To give an example in code:

```
struct test_object
{
    unsigned int value;
};

void function()
{
    // Declare a POINTER to an object of type <test_object>
    test_object *pointer;

    // Declare 2 temporary objects
    test_object object1, object2;

    // Set object1's value using the . operator
    object1.value = 1;
    // Set object2's value using the . operator
    object2.value = 2;


    // Set the pointer to point at object2
    // Note the usage of the & operator
    pointer = &object2;

    // Print out whatever the pointer points to (in this case object2)
    // Note the usage of -> instead of .
    // This is how pointers access the object being pointed at
    cout << pointer->value;


    // Now set the pointer to point at object1
    pointer = &object1;

    // Print out whatever the pointer points to (in this case object1)
    // Note this is the EXACT same line used above
    // but the end result is completely different
    cout << pointer->value;
};
```

---

A word of warning, pointers can be quite dangerous if used incorrectly. In the above example, I didn't initialize the pointer when I declared it...
IE:

```
test_object *pointer = NULL;
```

If you tried to use the COUT line in the above code without setting the pointer first, then really bad stuff can happen (program crashes, accessing the wrong memory location giving unexpected results, etc).

The best way to avoid such things is to **ALWAYS** initialize pointers to NULL, and **ALWAYS** check if the pointer is NULL before actually trying to access the memory being pointed to...

---

Re-using the above code, but making it safer:

```
void function()
{
    // Declare the pointer
    test_object *pointer = NULL;

    // Declare the 2 actual objects
    test_object object1, object2;

    // Set values
    object1.value = 1;
    object2.value = 2;


    // Check if pointer isn't pointing at anything
    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        // At this moment in time, it doesn't point at anything (it's still NULL)
        // So this code WON'T run, which stops the program crashing

        // Print out whatever the pointer points to
        cout << pointer->value;
    }

    // Set the pointer to point at object2
    pointer = &object2;

    // Check if pointer isn't pointing at anything
    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        // Now it DOES point to something (anything other than NULL)

        // Print out whatever the pointer points to
        cout << pointer->value;
    }
};
```

If you comment out the 2 if statements, then the program will probably crash when the first COUT is reached (it SHOULD crash, but not always).

---

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Here * means you are using pointers.Reason is that since Node could contain lot of variables and it would consume lot of memory So to avoid this we use pointers like

```
struct Node*
```

Since in this case when calling function and passing argument or returning argument of type Node you save lot of memory since in pointers only the address of the Node is passed or returned.Otherwise huge copy(If Node have lot of variables) of the Node will be made in memory before passing to or returning from the functions.
It is just like if I  take you to an apple store and go with you to buy them and in the pointer case I tell you only the address of the shop and you buy yourself.

Now coming to second part of your question `struct Node*` 
here function will return pointer of type struct Node so to use this you will write following code.

```
struct Node* someInput;
sturct Node* someOutput=create_ll(someInput);
```

and to use members inside someOutput for example if there are members like name and age inside Node you will do following

```
someOutput->age;
someOutput->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a pointer.
In this case it is returning a pointer of type struct node.

so the function prototype looks like

```
struct node *func(struct node *);
```